# flash database grid fill

Tags: database, flash, grid

I have a database on a server and I transfer the data from it to a web site. So I need to build a flash grid on this site and to load the data on it. But the problem is that I do not know how to do it. So my question is how to build a dynamic flash grid wich is fill with data from a database? Is there a way to do it with action script only or I must do it another way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [fl.controls.DataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html) component. There's good example code at that link.